# Public address for charity etc

Tags: transaction, address, address-reuse

not sure if i understand it correctly, but to me it seems as if any address is invalidated after receiving one incoming transaction.

If that is the case, is there a way to have a static, non-changing public address (like on vcard) that I can use to receive e.g. for charity, printing, ...? This is a pretty common use case imho and I am not sure how to address this one with IOTA

Comment: Address should not be re-used after a withdraw, but can be used many times to receive funds (i.e. no problem to receive many incoming transaction, but as soon as you withdraw one time  : all further incomming funds to this address will be at risk.)

Answer (score 1):

You can receive with an address as often as you want.

The problem is, when you send money from an address, you break the security.

Think of an iota address like a piggy bank. You can put as many money in as you want. If you want to spend, you break it. Any money you put into it after breaking is no longer protected.